# Instalar Facebook SDK no Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Preciso utilizar o SDK do Facebook em um aplicativo meu, mas eu simplesmente não consigo.
O aplicativo não tem nada, acabei de criar um novo. Acontece que as instruções que eles passam no Developers Facebook são muito vagas.

Comment: Deixe mais claro qual é o problema para alguém poder ajudar.

Comment: Eu não sei instalar o SDK do facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o [site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) no arquivo `/app/build.gradle`, antes das dependências :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Na parte das dependências  do build.gradle coloque:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

Depois disso, tem que ir no site do Facebook Developers e criar uma aplicação Android. Depois de criada, no Dashboard vai aparecer o App ID. O valor do App ID vai ser copiado e no arquivo de strings tem que ser criada uma string:

```
< string name="facebook_app_id" >(App ID)< /string >
```

Depois disso, no manifest tem que ser adicionado a seguinte linha:

```
< meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/ >
```

Aí é só dar um sync e build no Gradle e deve funcionar.